# how to logs error/success of snowsql command running from BAT file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i was running snowsql command through windows BAT file with -f option in snowsql, but i want to log acknowledgement detail after command run in SnowSQL.
i have tried with -o log file option but it has so many unnecessary information and i could not find actual success or failure massage. you can find command as below

```
snowsql -c confingname -o log_file=~/.snowsql/logfilename
```

is there way to have log file which display command and their acknowledgement in log file after execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to see the terminal output only, you can use output_file option:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-config.html#output-file

Comment: yes that worked but output file giving only result of command not that command that we execute, any way that enough for now my work will progress.